# JShell won't execute anything using Git Bash

Tags: java, git-bash, java-9, jshell

I installed Java9 (currently available version on [Oracle's site](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk9-downloads-3848520.html)) for Windows (Windows 10 x64 Professional, up to date as well, runs as a vmware virtual machine->VMware Workstation 12). I added the `jdk\bin` to the User's Path and tried to use [Git Bash](https://git-scm.com/downloads) to execute commands, but even though `JShell` launches, it won't execute any command after pressing `Enter`, it just sits there without doing anything.

Interesting thing is it works perfectly with Windows's default command line `CMD`or `Powershell`. If I recall correctly Git Bash is [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) based. What can be the cause of this?

Also, It is not connected directly to `JShell`, but I had similar problems on a different machine with some command line tools, like [JHipster](http://www.jhipster.tech/) (works on CMD but not on GitBash).

Obligatory screenshot:-

[image]

Edit.: Using `jshell -v` does not make a difference. Also, using any of the REPL helper commands, like `/help` or `/help intro` makes the shell to stop too.

Comment: Could you try starting the jshell in verbose mode using command `jshell -v` ans see if there are any logs pertaining to the failure.

Comment: @nullpointer Starting with `jshell -v` does not make a difference.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I had the same problem. The solution is simple:

"*If you are using git bash as your shell on Windows, add **winpty** before calling **jshell** ...*".

This is the source: https://kichwacoders.com/2017/05/25/woohoo-java-9-has-a-repl-getting-started-with-jshell-and-eclipse-january/

Here's **jshell** failing in Git Bash:

[image: jshell failing]

And here's **jshell** working in Git Bash when using **winpty**:

[image: jshell working with winpty]

And maybe this approach will also fix your JHipster problem?

[Updated to show clearer screen shots]

Comment: Did you build winpty or use the releases? I downloaded `winpty-0.4.3-cygwin-2.8.0-x64.tar.gz` but frankly was a bit confused regarding what to do with all the files in it.

Comment: _"Did you build winpty or use the releases?"_ => Neither. I was on Win10 and used Git Bash that comes bundled when you install Git, and there was nothing else I needed to do - **winpty** was simply there. But to be clear, if you want to use **jshell** on Windows just open a **cmd** window. The question here specifically relates to using jshell within a Git Bash window on Windows. (Or am I misunderstanding your question?)

Comment: @skomisa thanks for the clarification. I have since worked out how to get winpty and use it to launch JShell, which is what I was having issues with (turned out I had the wrong version of winpty, 34 vs 64 bit). :D